# Can't call function inside a python class

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, class, call

As the title says I can't call the function in my class. This is the code:

```
    def __init__(self, minimum, maximum, dobra_liczba):
        self.minimum = minimum
        self.maximum = maximum
        self.dobra_liczba = dobra_liczba

    def sprawdz_liczbe_int(self, liczba):
        print("sprawdzam liczbe")
        if isinstance(liczba, int) and self.minimum <= liczba <= self.maximum:

            return True
        else:
            return False

    def czy_liczba_trafiona(self, liczba):
        if liczba == self.dobra_liczba:
            print("trafiłeś!")
        else:
            print("pudło!")

    def graj(self):
        x = int(input("wpisz liczbe od "+str(self.minimum)+" do "+str(self.maximum)+": "))
        print(x)
        if self.sprawdz_liczbe_int(x) == True:
            self.czy_liczba_trafiona(x)

a1 = Gra(0, 100, 50)
a1.graj()
```

I can translate code to english if it will help.

This is guess a number game.

EDIT: I changed the code.

Comment: When calling a member function, don't pass `self` as the first argument. Ex: `if self.sprawdz_liczbe_int(input(....)) == True:`

Comment: Are you aware that you're passing `self` twice in `self.sprawdz_liczbe_int(self, ...)`?

Comment: i deleted self parameter but it still doesn't work.

Comment: `self.minimum <= liczba >= self.maximum` did you mean `self.minimum <= liczba <= self.maximum` there?

Comment: yes i meant that, little mistake but my code still doesn't works :(

Comment: What is `liczba == isinstance(liczba, int)` supposed to do?

Comment: check if liczba is integer

Comment: Then it should be `if True == isinstance(liczba, int) ...` or the more concise `if isinstance(liczba, int) ...`

Comment: i changed that but code still don't work

Comment: i tested it  on online compiler and it works, idk why

Comment: Between, what's the use of `self.liczba = liczba` in your code ?

Comment: it's guess a number game and the liczba is your guess

Answer (score 2):

You have passed the 'self' as a parameter wrongly, while calling the function.

Wrong:

```
sprawdz_liczbe_int(self.input("wpisz liczbe od"+str(self.minimum)+" do "+str(self.maximum)+”:")
```

Correction:

```
sprawdz_liczbe_int(input("wpisz liczbe od"+str(self.minimum)+" do "str(self.maximum)+":")
```

The main job of the 'self' keyword is to access the attributes and methods of the class in python.

To be more clear 'self' is always pointing to the object you are currently in.

Answer (score 0):

When calling a function in a class, don't add `self` as a parameter.
This line is where you went wrong.

```
sprawdz_liczbe_int(self,input("wpisz liczbe od "+str(self.minimum)+" do "+str(self.maximum)+": ")
```

try this instead.

```
class Gra:

    def __init__(self, minimum, maximum, liczba):
        self.minimum = minimum
        self.maximum = maximum
        self.liczba = liczba

    def sprawdz_liczbe_int(self, liczba):
        print("sprawdzam liczbe")
        if liczba == isinstance(liczba, int) and self.minimum <= liczba >= self.maximum:
            return True
        else:
            return False

    def graj(self):
        if self.sprawdz_liczbe_int(input("wpisz liczbe od "+str(self.minimum)+" do "+str(self.maximum)+": ")) == True:
            print("dobra liczba")
a1 = Gra(0, 100, 50) 
a1.graj()
```

Comment: i deleted self parameter but it still doesn't work.

Comment: no,  it justs stops and doesn't output anything after outputing "wpisz liczbe od 0 do 100:"

Comment: @kiciarozek That's supposed to be like that because of the `input()` you used in the code, now you supposed to type some value and validate it with the RETURN keyboard.

Comment: in first line of sprawdz_liczbe_int() there is print("sprawdzam liczbe"), but it doesn't print it

Comment: it will only print that once you have entered a number for the input

Comment: when i enter the number it ends

Comment: `isinstance(liczba, int)` is always `False` for user input. Additionally, `liczba == isinstance(liczba, int)` is almost always `False`.

Comment: can i use isinstance(int(liczba), int)?

Comment: i tested it  on online compiler and it works, idk why

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your condition is that you'll never get `True` because the `if liczba == isinstance(liczba, int)` always return `False`.

The value from the `input()` is a `String` or you test if `liczba` is an `int` and it's not the case so it's always `False`.

Maybe it's better if you omit it and just test if the value is inside the needed range number.

Comment: i made some changes in code like:
 `def graj(self):
        x = input("wpisz liczbe od "+str(self.minimum)+" do "+str(self.maximum)+": ")
        print(x)
        if self.sprawdz_liczbe_int(x) == True:
            self.czy_liczba_trafiona(x)`

i added print(x) to check if it will print x after getting input from user but it doesn't print it and program ends